# DynamicJasper + Struts 1

Tags: struts-1, dynamic-jasper

I saw that DynamicJasper integration with Struts 2 is possible and easy on the official doc.
But how about Struts 1 ?? is there a possible integration like with Struts 2?

Answer (score 2):

A regular file download should be enough... no need for anything special to have it integrated.
The logic to make the report should be in a service class, the action should call this service. The service should return a temporary file in order to let the action send it as response to the client as a regular file download.